# Reversing chars in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I was looking at a function that reverses an array of `char`s and I get everything, but the one thing that confuses me is the last statement inside the last `for` loop which is `line[j] = temp;`. I don't know what this is accomplishing.

```
    void reverse(char line[]) {

    char temp;
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; ++j)
        ;
    --j;

    if (line[j] == '\n') {
        --j;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        temp = line[i];

        line[i] = line[j];

        //This statement is the one in which I dont understand it's function
        line[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last line assigns what was in line[i] (now in temp) back into its new location at line[j].  Those 3 lines swap line[i] and line[j].

Comment: What do you think this one does: 'temp = line[i];' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply want to exchange two variables inside an array together . you won't be able to just do  `line[i] = line[j];` because the i'th item of the 'line' array will be overwritten by the j'th variable and it's initial value will be lost. so, in order to avoid i'th item from being lost, you first copy it in the 'temp' (`temp= line[i]`) , you overwrite `line[i]` by  `line[j]`, then copy temp (which is your initial value of `line[i]`)to `line[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

The last `for` run from `i` up and from `j` down until they meet in the middle, and switches those elements in the array.
In each iteration of the loop, the `i`th item is saved to `temp`, the `j`th item is placed in the `i`th place, and then the previously saved value, `temp`, is assigned to the `j`th place.